# Translation using GlobalLink

Tags: blueprint

We need to integrate GlobalLink for translation of Tridion items. As per my current understanding Tridion Translation works by configuring source and Targets (can be created for different layers as well like after English Content or for example Belgium case -multilingual). I was going through the Global Link documents but could not get enough about the configurations required and flow of the same. Logically the flow could be same but need to confirm. Can somebody help me on the differences in flow and configurations(whether source and targets required in GlobalLink as well).

Comment: for clarity, you want to know the differences in flow between the [GlobalLink Project Director Adaptor for Tridion](http://www.translations.com/products/globallink-tridion-adaptor) and [SDL Tridion Translation Manager](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-8178D205-83EE-4B12-A958-1FC4B2D8E48B) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion))?

Comment: Yes the flow and implementation(configurations) differences as well because in SDL Translation we set source and target but the same is not mentioned in Global link document so not sure if that process follows up in Global Link as well.

Comment: as far as I know the GlobalLink integration is built by them, not sure if anybody heard of it or used it, so I think you can best ask them directly on the differences.

Comment: No issues Bart, let me ask you one simple question.Global content has to be translated.In Translation layer, all the components will be checked out and get localised before translation.Now again my Global content changes, will this new changes be inherited by translation layer as the components are localised and inheritance link is broken. In Tridion translation process, new content flows to translation layer after translation. So I guess in case of Global link, process will be the same, just want to confirm??

Comment: When you change your parent (global) item, your localized items are not changed. you would send the parent (global) item off for translation again, just as if it hasn't been translated yet. The idea is, when your translation system has translation memory the costs of this (second) translation, will be less than the initial one because the unchanged parts are already translated.

Comment: So I can say that whenever there will be a change in "Global Content" and after translation happens, the content in the translation layer will always be "overridden" by the new translated content.

Comment: That is how SDL managed translation (SDL WorldServer, TMS, or BeGlobal) approaches work, but be careful with "always" and "overridden" (do you mean a new version?). Typically unchanged items are not re-translated. It seems GlobalLink has a similar option (have you read their [PDF brief](http://www.translations.com/sites/default/files/imported/pdfs/Translations.com_AdaptorBrief_Tridion.pdf) which suggests translations are imported back into "target publications?"). But really, you need to confirm with the vendor.

Comment: I removed [tag:translation-manager] as this isn't specific to `Translation Manager`. Since it's related to *managed translations* I added [tag:blueprint].

Comment: Were you able to get an answer to your question? I'll see if GlobalLink might answer directly. :-)

Comment: Couldn't find a Twitter handle so I posted [this](https://twitter.com/Nivlong/status/496912684730707968) instead.